# Why are UUID / GUID's in the format they are?

Tags: uuid

[Globally Unique Identifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) (GUID) are a grouped string with a specific format which I assume has a security reason.

> A GUID is most commonly written in text as a sequence of hexadecimal
>   digits separated into five groups, such as:
>
> 3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301

Why aren't GUID/UUID strings just random bytes encoded using hexadecimal of X length?

> This text notation contains the following fields, separated by
>   hyphens:
>
> ```
> | Hex digits | Description
> |-------------------------
> | 8            | Data1
> | 4            | Data2
> | 4            | Data3
> | 4            | Initial two bytes from Data4
> | 12           | Remaining six bytes from Data4
> ```

There are also [several versions of the UUID standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

> Version 4 UUIDs are generally internally stored as a raw array of 128
>   bits, and typically displayed in a format something like:
>
> uuid:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: No, it probably isn't for security reasons, the bitstring has the same entropy with or without the dashes. I would think it is so that GUID's can be recognized at a glance instead of going "here's a bunch of hex characters, is that md5.. or perhaps sha1.. no, wait, it could be..." and so on. Also, GUID's are usually not just random bytes.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/27/8659071.aspx

Comment: Similar Question from SO [UUID format: 8-4-4-4-12 - Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10687505/1671639)

Comment: [specific to the latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47230521/1739000) (version 4)

Answer (score 12):

From [RfC4122 – A Universally Unique IDentifier (UUID) URN Namespace](http://Tools.IETF.Org/html/rfc4122/)

> The formal definition of the UUID string representation is provided by the following ABNF:
>
> ```
> UUID                   = time-low "-" time-mid "-"
>                          time-high-and-version "-"
>                          clock-seq-and-reserved
>                          clock-seq-low "-" node
> ```

So, those are just the different fields from the original [time and MAC-based UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_.28MAC_address.29). The RFC says it originates from the Apollo Network Computing System.

Answer (score 2):

The text representation with the dashes is separating the four fields of the Guid/UUID into five groups (with the last field being separated itself after the first two bytes): [Guid Text Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guid#Text_encoding)

The representation doesn't have anything to do with security, as there are different methods of computing it and is intended to be a unique identifier not necessarily a secure one.

The most likely reason the fields are split (even though the standard doesn't mention it) is for readability/separation of the component parts.

Comment: That tells us what the format is, information that was already in the question. It doesn't explain *why*, which is what the OP was asking.

Comment: It is just separating them into the fields, likely for better readability and identification.  Maybe the last one was split further because of its length.

Comment: logical. Same reason phone numbers, credit card numbers, and many other long numbers are frequently split up in groups when printed or written down.